# ASP.NET Core JsonResult возвращает неправильный результат

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2

Изучая данную технологию, столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Делаю Rest-API, из контроллера хочу вернуть объект `UserOutput`, который содержит несколько свойств, одно из которых `Body` - представляет из себя `UserEntity[]`.

Объект `UserOutput` конвертирую в `JsonResult` при помощи метода `Controller.Json()`.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
{
   "status" : true,
   "errorMessage" : null,
   "body" : [ // Массив объектов UserEntity
       {
           "id" : 1,
           "firstName" : "SomeName",
           "lastName" : "SomeSurname",
           "middleName" : null
       },
       {
           "id" : 1,
           "firstName" : "SomeName",
           "lastName" : "SomeSurname",
           "middleName" : null
       }
   ]
}
```

Сущность пользователя:

```
public class UserEntity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

// ... Кострукторы и прочие несущественные методы
```

Класс ответа (если так можно выразиться):

```
public class UserOutput
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public UserEntity[] Body { get; set; }

    public static UserOutput Success(UserEntity[] entities)
    {
        return new UserOutput() { Status = true, Body = entities};
    }

    public static UserOutput Failure(string errorMessage)
    {
        return new UserOutput() { Status = false, ErrorMessage = errorMessage };
    }
}
```

Метод класса `UserModel` (Буду признателен, если подскажите правильное именование модулей, классов и т.д)
P.S. `UserRepository` работает нормально

```
public UserOutput GetAllUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            UserEntity[] users = UserRepository.GetAll();

            if (users.Count() == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("There are was no Users found!");
            }

            return UserOutput.Success(users);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return UserOutput.Failure(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Метод контроллера (переменные добавил, чтобы дебагом проверить(скрин дебага ниже)):

```
[HttpGet][Route("get/all")]
public JsonResult GetAllUsers()
{
    var response = UserModel.GetAllUsers();
    var jsonResponse = Json(response);
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Скрины:

[image: Пример ответа 1]
[image: Пример ответа 2]
[image: Дебаг]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Ни кода контроллера, ни кода класса, ни текущего результата, ни описания проблемы. Вы какой ответ рассчитываете получить?

Comment: @tym32167 случайно сохранил неготовый вопрос, и сразу же отправился доделывать его))

Comment: @AK Поменял скрины на код. Я не часто задаю вопросы на форумах, поэтому не знал как лучше, почему-то вначале подумал, что скринами понятнее будет. Вижу, что ошибся. Благодарю за критику и совет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я подобное видел пару раз, когда мне было лень писать dto классы и я отправил на сериализацию классы самого Entity Framework Code First (там были циклические ссылки между сущностями), поэтому json просто обрывался на каком-то месте. С тех пор - как бабка отшептала ;)

Я не вижу вообще никаких не то, что циклических ссылок - но просто вообще ссылок на другие сущности. Поэтому до конца не уверен, что именно в этом ошибка. Но всё-таки попробуйте сделать такой же класс как UserEntity и отправлять на сериализацию его. В самом простом варианте:

```
public class UserEntityDto
{
   public UserEntitityDto(UserEntity entity)
   {
        // TODO: automapper по настроению
        this.Id = entity.Id;
        this.FirstName = entity.FirstName;
        ... и т.п.
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}

public class UserOutput
{
    public UserEntityDto[] Body { get; set; }
}

UserEntity[] users = UserRepository.GetAll();
UserentityDto[] body = users.Select(x => new UserEntityDto(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, за помощь! Проблема решена)
C# я знаю относительно мало, и как такового опыта в нем еще нет, поэтому не до конца понял в чем суть проблемы и почему все заработало))

Comment: @ЗаурНадиралиев Прямо говоря, я точно не уверен, в чём была причина: просто с опытом у вас приходит понимание, какими тропками ходить нельзя и вы туда и не ходите никогда. И поэтому порой сложно по описанию проблемы вообще понять, что не так - так как ты давно не ходил туда. Я вот лично знаю, что в той стороне несколько типичных ошибок бывает при сериализации (например, нет некоторых атрибутов для сериализации - не в вашем случае, но и такое могло), поэтому не знаю точно, какая именно у вас была. Этот тот случай, что сколько ни говори новичку так не делать - пока сами не наступят не поймут.